# Is it possible to pass array as props after mounted()?

Tags: javascript, spring, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have app using VueJS + Vuetify + Spring. I'm getting a travel list from server and I want to display the list of names in a navigation drawer.
I created a `travelList` array and I want to fetch this list of travels before `drawerElements` passes it to the navigation drawer as a prop.

Is it possible? My current code doesn't work - probably I did something wrong, maybe there is another, better and correct way.

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <app-bar/>
    <navigation-drawer :links="drawerElements"/>
    <v-main>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import AppBar from "@/views/components/AppBar";
import NavigationDrawer from "@/views/components/NavigationDrawer";
import TravelService from "@/services/travel.service";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {AppBar, NavigationDrawer},
  data() {
    return {
      travelList: [],
      drawerElements: [
        {
          to: '/menu/home',
          icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard',
          text: 'Home',
        },
        {
          icon: 'mdi-book-multiple',
          text: 'Travels',
          subLinks: this.travelList,
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    currentUser() {
      return this.$store.state.auth.user;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if (!this.currentUser) {
      this.$router.push('/login');
    }
    this.getTravelList();

  },
  methods: {
    getTravelList() {
      TravelService.getLoggedUserTravels().then(
          response => {
            this.convertTravelToDrawerElements(response.data);
          }
      )
    },
    convertTravelToDrawerElements(response) {
      let travels = [];
      response.forEach(element => {
        let travel = {};
        travel.text = element.name;
        travel.to = '/trip/' + element.id;
        travel.icon = "mdi-menu-right";
        travels.push(travel);
      })
      this.travelList = travels;
    }
  },
}
</script>
<style>

</style>
```

Comment: Maybe try changing subLinks to a function: `subLinks: function () { return this.travelList }`

Comment: @BrandonPratt unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: how about using `v-if`?

Comment: Since `drawerElements` is based on `travelList`, make it a computed prop.

Comment: @bbbbburton thanks, I used second way from Michal Levy comments. But I think you're idea also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options

1. Inside your `convertTravelToDrawerElements` method, `push` every created `travel` directly into `this.travelList` instead of replacing it with a new array
2. Convert `drawerElements` from `data` into computed property

```js
computed: {
  getDrawerElements() {
    return [
        {
          to: '/menu/home',
          icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard',
          text: 'Home',
        },
        {
          icon: 'mdi-book-multiple',
          text: 'Travels',
          subLinks: this.travelList,
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <app-bar/>
    <navigation-drawer :links="getDrawerElements"/>
    <v-main>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

## The reason

...your code doesn't work as expected is because `data()` function is called **only once** when your component is created. At that time, the `this.travelList` is empty array. This empty array (or better say [reference to the array](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/)) is assigned into `subLinks` property of the new object the `data()` function creates and returns. When you later replace the `this.travelList` with a new array, the operation has no effect on the content of `subLinks` property, it still contains the reference to the previous (and completely empty) array....

Comment: Second way solved my problem, thank you! Before I asked my question i tried to make this solutions, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Glad it helped. Do you actually understand why you code didnt work as expected ?

Comment: I don't know I correctly read... Variables in computed reacts for changes and automatically re-renders components, and data no so we need to use watcher?

Comment: `data` is also rective in Vue. Hope my updated answer makes it more clear. Keep learning!